# can't access object in array PHP

Tags: php

Have tried every variation I can think of to access an object property in an array. I'm getting some data back form an API which i'm storing in a variable called $userTokenValid:

```
$userTokenValid = [{"authTokenValid":1}];
```

i'm then trying to access the authTokenValid property like so:

```
echo json_decode($userTokenValid[0]->authTokenValid);
```

I appreciate this might be quite basic but can't spot where I have gone wrong.

Comment: try a `var_dump($userTokenValid)`

Comment: result is string(27) " [{"authTokenValid":1}]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$userTokenValid` isn't valid php. However `[{"authTokenValid":1}]` is a valid json string.

```
$userTokenValid = '[{"authTokenValid":1}]';
```

you can decode it with

```
$json = json_decode($userTokenValid);
```

finally

```
echo $json[0]->authTokenValid;
```